# Can't verify 2nd email address on PayPal

Tags: paypal

I want transaction info on PayPal to be sent to 2 different email addresses. The 2nd email address was "unconfirmed" and there was a message to "Confirm this email". I've clicked this a few times but I still get no email about confirming at either the 1st or 2nd email address. What can I do?

Comment: Call Paypal. This is not a place to receive support for general account issues.

Answer (score -1):

I just tested this to see if I could confirm a second address and an email was promptly sent.

Comment: Doesn't work for me. When I add a new address I see  "That email address isn't available. Do you want to add another one?"  For the addresses that were unconfirmed, I click the  "Unconfirmed" link and get to a page that says "Check your email"....but no email ever comes.